# LLAMA-2 model download is failing

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, llama-cpp-python

I've got the token from huggingface and I was able to login with huggingface-cli. I also got approval to download 7B-hf model. When I started inference run, model download started well but it is now stuck at `Map` and it is not completing.

What did I miss?

```
Loading checkpoint shards: 100%| . . . | 2/2 [00:01<00:00,  1.83it/s]
Data type of the model: torch.float32
Map:   0%| . . .| 0/2662 [00:00<?, ? examples/s]
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Get approval from Meta for the model (e.g. meta-llama/Llama-2-70b-chat-hf) -> check in huggingface in model's page how to get Meta's authorization
2. Create a read token from here : https://huggingface.co/settings/tokens
3. `pip install transformers`
4. Execute `huggingface-cli login` and provide the read token -> note the token is not shown in terminal but is there when u paste
5. Run the script, should work

Seems you've got the auth and the token, but try another model.
For me the model *meta-llama/Llama-2-70b-chat-hf* worked but the model *meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf* got stuck forever in one of the downloads.

Answer (score -1):

Try updating the transformers module:

```
$pip install --upgrade transformers
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried. Still the same problem.